# Julia Interact widgets not reacting

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, julia, interactive, ijulia-notebook

I've been having a weird issue for a long time now. I've tried multiple things, but they only worked temporarily at best.

I'm using the Julia package "Interact.jl" in Jupyter Notebook to create some interactive plots. But the problem occurs generally with all Interact widgets.

The widget UI is rendered correctly, and the initial output is computed as well. However, the output is not updated when I click on any of the widgets. The widget UI reacts to my click, making me think I can interact with it, but the output just stays still. The kernel does not do anything at all, as far as I can tell from the little indicator in the top right corner.

More info on my setup: I'm running Julia version 1.4.1 on Windows 10 (64 bit). Jupyter Notebook is running in the latest version of Firefox, with JavaScript enabled.

I have tried the following things. Some of them did nothing, sometimes the problem seemed to be fixed but then reappeared minutes or days later.

- disabled adblockers and tracking blockers in Firefox (temporary success)
- updated Firefox to the latest version (temporary success)
- used Microsoft Edge (without any add-ons) instead of Firefox (no success)
- switched to the latest Julia version 1.5.3 (no success)
- used `Pkg.build` (temporary success)
- installed Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda instead of via IJulia (temporary success)

Actually, before I started typing this, I opened the notebook and checked if the widgets react: they didn't. But when I check right now, the widgets seem to have caught up somehow and updated the output multiple times.
I've never seen this delayed behavior during the past few months that I had the issue, so I'm not sure whether this is always what happens.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I found a solution in another forum.
Each time you open the interactive notebook, do the following:

1. Select *Cell > All Output > Clear* in the Jupyter Menu
2. Save the Notebook
3. Restart the kernel

A little bit inconvenient, but it worked consistently so far.

Comment: I'm not sure this belongs here, is there a code issue preventing this? If so please post the relevant sections.

Comment: I guess it's not a code issue, but some kind of compatibility issue?
The described problem occurs generally, even for super simple widgets like
```@manipulate for i in ["1","2"]; println(i); end```
If this doesn't belong here, I'm sorry, as I'm new to StackExchange. Is there a better site to direct me to?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Julia (it seems like it's a webapp), but it may be worth checking their support forums and/or comparing their minium spec with your setup? ie are you using a browser that's not supported, too old or too new?

Comment: No, Julia is a locally installed programming language: https://julialang.org/
It's comparable to Python in many ways. The browser just serves as the renderer for the html-based editor called Jupyter, which is also locally installed. The entire setup works without an internet connection

Comment: I've posted my question on the official Julia forums now as well. So if you think this doesn't belong here, feel free to delete it